# Sort an array so that first half is in ascending order, second half is in descending order in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort an array so that first half should be in ascending order and the second half should be in descending order in PHP.

```
{3,1,2,4,9,8,7,6,5,10}
```

result

```
{1,2,3,4,5,10,9,8,7,6}
```

Comment: what you have tried till now? please post here?

Comment: Split the array in two, sort them independently, join them back together.

Comment: Do you make Paypal payments? Or Bitcoin?

Comment: sort the array.... split it in two, reverse sort the second part, merge the two back together again

Comment: Instead of posting a question think for a while you will get the answer. Take inputs from halfer comment

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$arr = array(3,1,2,4,9,8,7,6,5,10);
sort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
//print_r($arr);
$arr_chunk = array_chunk($arr, ceil(count($arr)/2));
//print_r($arr_chunk);
$reversed_arr = array_reverse($arr_chunk[1]);
$final_arr = array_merge($arr_chunk[0],$reversed_arr);
print_r($final_arr);
?>
```

Comment: `rsort($arr_chunk[1], SORT_NUMERIC);
$final_arr = array_merge($arr_chunk[0],$arr_chunk[1]);` uses slightly less memory than `array_reverse()`